# Yocto Bsp Porting in non dts sdk

Tags: c, embedded-linux, yocto

We are using the yocto sdk for x86 platform for intel.The below is the link of source code.
https://minnowboard.org/tutorials/installing-yocto-poky

since the sdk for minnow board (x86) is a non dts based can you please guide us on how can we add support in source code for a particular interface.How can we configure a spi interface for CAN Controller in yocto in non dts platform.

Comment: You may need to have a look on ACPI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310935/difference-between-dts-and-acpi

Comment: Look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768841/building-a-i2c-device-controller/54967620#54967620, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64/46370798#46370798  Also take a look at meta-acpi project: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/